# How to set "Best Reply" in Sharepoint Discussion using c#

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Discussion list in SharePoint online. It has few Questions and each question has few replies too.

I would like to know how to set "Best reply" using c# . List settings does not contain a column for best reply. So there must be some other way to set this value.

I could not find much information regarding this. Any pointer will be really valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sample code for your reference.

```
var web = clientContext.Web;
                var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("DiscussionBoard");
                //get disscussion by disscussion item id, for production, it should be based on caml query
                var item = list.GetItemById(2);
                //set best reply by reply item id, for production, it should be based on caml query
                item["BestAnswerId"]=7;
                item.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Can we do same using REST api?